# The largest $\ell_p$-norm of a sum of rows of a Sylvester-Hadamard-Walsh matrix

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, matrices, inequalities, binomial-distribution

Given any $n\in\mathbb N$, consider the [the Sylvester-Hadamard-Walsh matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walsh_matrix) $M=(a_{i,j})_{i,j\in 2^n}$ of size $2^n\times 2^n$ and for a number $p\in[1,\infty)$, let
$$\nu_{n,p}=\max_{F\subseteq 2^n}\Big(\sum_{j\in 2^n}\big|\sum_{i\in F}a_{i,j}\big|^p\Big)^{1/p}\quad\mbox{and}\quad \tilde \nu_{n,p}=\frac1{2^{2^n}}\sum_{F\subseteq 2^n}\Big(\sum_{j\in 2^n}\big|\sum_{i\in F}a_{i,j}\big|^p\Big)^{1/p}.$$
For $p=2$, the Pithagoras Theorem and the orthogonality of the rows of the matrix $M$ imply that $\nu_{n,2}=2^n$. Using this equality, it is easy to show that $\nu_{n,p}=2^n$ for all $p\in[2,\infty)$.

If $p\in[1,2]$, then by the Holder inequality, we obtain
$$2^n\le\nu_{n,p}\le 2^{n(\frac1p+\frac12)}.$$ In particular, $2^n\le\nu_{n,1}\le 2^{3n/2}$. On the other hand, computer calculations show that $\tilde \nu_{n,1}$ and $\nu_{n,1}$ are much smaller than $2^{3n/2}$ (the values of $\tilde\nu_{n,1}$ are calculated using the formula
$$\tilde\nu_{n,1}=\frac1{2^{2^n}}\Big(\sum_{i=0}^{2^n}{2^n\choose i}i+2(2^n-1)\sum_{0\le i<j\le 2^n}{2^n\choose i}{2^n\choose j}(j-i)\Big)$$
of Alex Ravsky suggested in his comment):
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
n&2^n&\tilde \nu_{n,1}&\nu_{n,1}&\lfloor 2^{3n/2}\rfloor&\tilde\nu_{n,1}/2^{3n/2}\\
\hline
0&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&2&1.5&2&2&0.53...\\
2&4&4.25&6&8&0.53...\\
3&8&11.65...&14&22&0.51...\\
4&16&31.56...&40&64&0.49...\\
5&32&85.41...&\ge 96&181&0.47...\\
6&64&232.28..&??&512&0.45...\\
7&128&636.09...&??&1448&0.43...\\
8&256&1754.09...&??&4096&0.42...\\
9&512&4866.56...&??&11585&0.42...\\
\end{array}
$$

> **Problem 1.** Is $\nu_{n,1}\ge\frac12 2^{3n/2}$? Is $\tilde\nu_{n,1}\ge \varepsilon 2^{3n/2}$ for some $\varepsilon>0$?
>
> **Problem 2.** Is $\tilde\nu_{n,1}=o(2^{3n/2})$? Is $\nu_{n,1}=o(2^{3n/2})$?
>
> **Problem 3.** Find nontrivial lower and upper bounds on the number $$\lambda_1=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\log_2(\nu_{n,1}).$$ Is $1<\lambda_1<\frac32$?

Comment: Erm... If you just choose $F$ randomly, then the typical size of the sum over $F$ is $2^{n/2}$ for each $j$, so you get $\nu_{n,p}$ comparable to the trivial Holder bound. Whether the comparability constant is above $1/2$ or not for $p=1$ may be harder to determine, but do you really care?

Comment: Maximising the function $\nu_{n, 1}$ is equivalent to maximising $\sum_{H} |X| - 2|X \cap H|$ where $X \subseteq \mathbb{F}_{2}^{n}$, and the sum is over hyperplanes of $\mathbb{F}_{2}^{n}$. So the function is large when $X$ is 'unbalanced' with respect to many hyperplanes. Perhaps there is a construction for such objects in the finite geometry literature?

Comment: @fedja In fact, for my purposes it would be nice to have affirmative answer to Problem 2.   Could you prove that there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that for a sufficiently large $n$ and randomly chosen $F$ the probablity to have $\sum_{j\in 2^n}|\sum_{i\in F}a_{i,j}|>\varepsilon 2^{3n/2}$ is positive?

Comment: It seems the following. We have that $$2^{2^n}\tilde \nu_{n,1}=\sum_{F\subseteq 2^n}\sum_{j\in 2^n}\big|\sum_{i\in F}a_{i,j}\big|=\sum_{j\in 2^n} S_j$$ where $S_j=\sum_{F\subseteq 2^n}\big|\sum_{i\in F}a_{i,j}\big|$. Let $j\in 2^n$ and $j\ne 0$. Since there is exactly $2^{n-1}$ elements $i\in 2^n$ such that $a_{i,j}=1$, 
$$S_j=\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}} \sum_{\ell=0}^{2^{n-1}} {2^{n-1}\choose k}{2^{n-1}\choose \ell}|k-\ell|.$$

Comment: @TarasBanakh But what I said immediately implies the negative answer to problem 2, doesn't it?

Comment: @fedja Probably yes, modulo some calculations of probabilities. In any case, I stopped to believe that Problem 2 has affirmative answer.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Sasha, thank you for your comment. Everything works and computer calculations using your formula agree with known values of $\tilde \nu_{n,1}$ for $n\le 4$.

Comment: I installed MathCad and I shall try to guess the asymptotics of $\tilde \nu_{n,1}$ via the formula.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Python was able to calclulate $\tilde\nu_{n,1}$ only for $n<10$. For $n=10$ it had Overflow Error (without Math).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\tnu}{\tilde\nu}$Continuing Alex Ravsky's comment, we have
\begin{equation*}
    2^{2^n}\tnu_{n,1}=\sum_{j=0}^{2^n-1}S_j=S_0+(2^n-1)S_1, \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    S_j:=\sum_{F\subseteq[2^n]}\Big|\sum_{i\in F}a_{i,j}\Big|,
\end{equation*}
and for each $j\ne0$
\begin{equation*}
    S_j=S_1=\sum_{k,l=0}^M\binom Mk \binom Ml |k-l|,
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    M=M_n:=2^{n-1}. \tag{2}
\end{equation*}

So,
\begin{equation*}
    S_1=2^{2M} E|K-K'|, \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
where, for each natural $n$, $K=K_n$ and $K'=K'_n$ are independent random variables (r.v.'s) each with the binomial distribution with parameters $M,1/2$. By the central limit theorem, the distribution of $(K-M/2)/\sqrt{M/4}$ converges weakly to the standard normal distribution (as $n\to\infty$), and hence $V_n:=(K-K')/\sqrt{M/4}$ converges in distribution to $Z-Z'$, where $Z$ and $Z'$ are independent standard normal r.v.'s.

Also, $EV_n^2=2<\infty$ for all $n$ and hence, by the [de la Vallée-Poussin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability#Relevant_theorems), the $V_n$'s are uniformly integrable.

Therefore (see e.g. [Theorem 3.5, p. 31](http://cermics.enpc.fr/%7Emonneau/Billingsley-2eme-edition.pdf)), $E|V_n|\to E|Z-Z'|$ and hence, by (3),
\begin{equation*}
    S_1\sim 2^{2M}  \sqrt{\frac M4}\;E|Z-Z'|=2^{2M}  \sqrt{\frac M4}\;\frac2{\sqrt\pi}. \tag{4}
\end{equation*}

Also,
\begin{equation*}
    S_0=\sum_{F\subseteq[2^n]}\sum_{i\in F}1=\sum_{k=0}^{2M}\binom{2M}k k=2^{2M}M. \tag{5}
\end{equation*}
Collecting the pieces (1), (5), (4), and (2), we finally get
\begin{equation*}
    \tnu_{n,1}\sim\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,2^{3n/2}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! By the way, $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}= 0.398942...$ which agrees with calculations of initial values of $\tilde\nu_{n,1}$.